# How to mount a tube to a grease fitting?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I have a piece of mahinery with a grease fitting in an awkward to reach place. The fitting is of this shape ...

[image]

... but not screwed into place but pressed. So we can't have it removed and replaced with a pipe leading to a more accessible place. 
My question is: Can I mount a tube to the fitting in a way that it stays there for the foreseeable future (a few years)? Grease will be applied twice a year. I have doubts that simply pushing a tube over the fitting and applying a clamp will suffice, as greasing will put some pressure on the thing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem appears to have a commercial solution. Using the Google, I searched for "locking grease coupler" and found a number of products with guaranteed no-leak connections.

https://locknlube.com/ appears to be using fittings with a release mechanism that can be separated from the attached hose, or perhaps the other end of the hose can be modified for your specific application.

[image: locking coupler]

https://www.gurtech.co.za/locknlube-grease-coupler/ references a locking seal up to 690 bar / 10,000 psi with no release or leaking. It also appears to have a threaded joint to which other hoses could be attached.

[image: locking fitting]

It's feasible to consider that the locking lever can be removed if access is tight/restricted, as long as the spring forces are not modified in the process.

Comment: Between asking this question and your answer, I reached out to a supplier and was told the same - though they stress that a long term guarantee, that the coupling wil remain in place, can not be given. I'd advise against such a solution when the grease fitting can't be seen while applying grease, but for my application it's ok ...

Answer (score 0):

Did you also consider a 90 or 60 degree grease fitting. It would be a cheaper solution to piping to a remote manifold.

https://www.mcmaster.com/#grease-fittings/=1c3ojei